# How do we map complex NativeQuery results to a DTO objects using java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(STUDENT_QUERY_WITH_PARAMS);
        query.setParameter("studentId", stduentId);
        query.setParameter("startDate", valueOf(startDate), TemporalType.DATE);
        query.setParameter("endDate", valueOf(endDate), TemporalType.DATE);
        List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();

        List<StudentDepartmentCatDTO> result = new ArrayList<>(resultList.size());
        for (Object[] row : resultList) {
            result.add(new StudentDepartmentCatDTO((String)row[0], (String)row[1], (String)row[2], null,(UUID)row[4], (Integer)row[5], (Integer)row[6], (Integer)row[7], (Integer)row[8], null, null, null, null ));
        }
```

`I have SQL query to pull the certain data from various tables by joining multiple tables(in my case 13 tables) and I am able to get all the results back successfully but when I try to map these results back to DTO I am getting cast exceptions. How do I overcome these exceptions?

B cannot be cast to class java.util.UUID and 
class java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer

Since All the results are coming from various tables, I didnt find a way to do this using SqlResultSetMapping as none of the managed entities can be directly mapped to the results. Is there a better way to do this? and I how to fix these cast exceptions?  Can I create the unmanaged entity to map all the results to it? How do I extract the sql results to my DTO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [use an `@SqlResultSetMapping` to convert each record in your result set to a DTO](https://thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/) object. But that would require an additional constructor so that you don't need to set any parameters to `null`.

Here is an example of such a mapping. As you can see, you need to reference the elements in your result set by their name, but you didn't share your query. So, I can't adapt the example to your query.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "BookValueMapping",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = BookValue.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "title"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "version", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "authorName")}))
```

I use this mapping with a query that selects the `id`, `title`, `version` and `authorName` column from the database. The `@ConstructorResult` annotation describes a constructor call of the `BookValue` class. The `@ColumnResult` annotations define the constructor parameters and their order. You need to make sure that the instantiated class provides a constructor that matches these parameters.

`@SqlResultSetMapping` is a powerful and flexible feature in JPA. I explain it in great details here: https://thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/

---

OK, let's now take a look at the class cast issue ...

The cast fails because the two objects are of the wrong class. `row[4]` seems to be a `byte[]` and one of `row[6/7/8]` (or all of them) seems to be a BigInteger.

This code snippet should help you to convert the byte[] to a UUID:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
long high = bb.getLong();
long low = bb.getLong();
UUID uuid = new UUID(high, low);
```

The conversion of a `BigDecimal` to an `Integer` is much easier. You just need to call the `intValueExact()` method on your `BigDecimal`, e.g. `row[6].intValueExact();`.

Comment: Thank you Janssen, I went through the article it is very helpful  in our current code base we have used the SQLResultMapping everywhere but this is a special case scenario where we don't have managed entity to query against. This is a odd scenario we are joining 12 tables and 12 tables. We have seperated all our entity mapping to 3 different api services so cant map all the entities on joins